# Modernizing the look of Application.Messagebox for Windows 11

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, messagebox, windows-11

Is there a method to modernize how the `Application.MessageBox()` dialog looks in Win11? Perhaps by creating a manifest file or something to make classic desktop app to look newer?

Comment: Aren't you already using a manifest? But IIRC Delphi 7 doesn't use the system dialogs for `Application.MessageBox`. You can just call the Windows API `MessageBox` instead, making sure you have the comctl v6 manifest, and you will get the native system dialog.

Comment: Is it just me wondering about people asking for modernizing their application while insisting on using an outdated development tool?

Comment: It's usually not their decision.

Comment: The comment fits for anyone else up in the responsibility chain.

Comment: @UweRaabe up until a few months ago, I was still using C++Builder 6 to write my company's software, and it had perfectly modernized UIs.  You don't always need updated tools to use updated APIs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word, no.

`Application.MessageBox()` calls the Win32 `MessageBox()` API, which is an old dialog.

For a newer look, you need to use the Win32 [Task Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/task-dialogs) that was introduced in Windows Vista, instead of using `MessageBox()`.

Modern Delphi versions have a `TTaskDialog` component, and `TaskMessageDlg...()` wrapper functions in the `(Vcl.)Dialogs` unit. But those do not exist in Delphi 7, so you will have to define and import the Task Dialog API types and functions manually.

Comment: And you may want to use a more convenient interface, like https://specials.rejbrand.se/dev/classes/TDMessageBox/TDMessageBox.html (disclaimer: my site).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Did I already ask you to implement the `CTRL+C` feature, so all the dialog's content goes to the clipboard as text?

Comment: @AmigoJack: I don't remember, but my `TDMessageBox.pas` is just a wrapper around the `TTaskDialog`, so it is a native Win32 task dialog. Therefore, it *does* support Ctrl+C.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Ah yes, now I see it, too. Great!

Comment: [mORMot makes `TTaskDialog` available](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SynTaskDialog.pas) to D6 and up for those who don't want to implement it manually.